# How to make an object's X and Y positions responsive to HTML Canvas's width and height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am building a simple game using HTML5 Canvas.

The game has multiple rectangles inside the canvas.

The issue is that I am using X and Y coordinates to control the rectangles; the game works great on my display—however, if I use a smaller display, the object can move outside the "map". If I use a bigger display, I can see more of the "map".

How can I make it responsive?

Here's part of the code that I use to create the canvas:

```
    this.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth - 15;
    this.canvas.height = 700;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
```

and this is pretty much the rectangle's movement inside a game loop:

```
    cursor.x += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set both the canvas width **and** height so that they can not be larger than the screen size.

Then, each time you move the rectangle, add a check to see if the rectangle is still within the viewport.

So something like:

```
if (cursor.x + 1 < this.canvas.width) {
  cursor.x += 1;
}
```